# How to compare 2 PDF files

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script to compare 2 PDF files. But I'm unable to write my script. Some times I'm getting:

> ```
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
> At C:\demo2\koti\Untitled2.ps1:16 char:2
> +     $pdf.Close()
> +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
> ```

How to write the script by using PowerShell.

Comment: There currently isn't enough information here to understand what you're trying to do. If you have a specific issue with your script, edit your question to include the script and the complete error message. If the script relies on something specific in the PDF files, consider making those available as well.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Do you want to check if the PDF's are exactly the same? Do you want to get a visual "diff" of the page? Do you want to compare the texts?

Comment: If you want to visually compare them I'd reccommend checking out the `compare` command from [imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/)

Comment: If you need text based comparing, use `pdftotext` and then use diff

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, or what command throws the error, but I'm going to give you a way to compare PDFs visually and by text.

### Visually

There is no Windows builtin command to compare PDFs so, we have to install some tool. Here you need to install [imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/) and [PDFtk Server](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/).
After installing these, you should run the commands:

```
compare -verbose -debug coder [first PDF].PDF [second PDF].PDF -compose src [output file].tmp
pdftk [output file].tmp background [first PDF].PDF output [output file]
```

The first command compares the files and fills the differences with red pixels, while the second merges the red pixels with `[first PDF]`.

#### Note

If you need to compare multi-page PDF files, you have to first divide them into single page files, it's possible to achieve this with `pdftk`

```
pdftk  [first].PDF   burst  output  [somewhere]/[first]---page_%03d.pdf
pdftk  [second].PDF  burst  output  [somewhere]/[second]---page_%03d.pdf
```

### Textually

There is no "PDF-to-Text" converter on Windows by default either, so let's install it. [This tool called XpdfReader seems to get the job done](http://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html) .
Now, you need to run the commands:

```
pdftotext [first PDF].PDF
pdftotext [second PDF].PDF
[difftool] [first PDF].txt [second PDF].txt
```

`[difftool]` is just whatever tool you want to use to compare .txt files. On power shell this can be:

```
compare-object (get-content [first].txt) (get-content [second].txt)
```

Or something different, like `vimdiff`.

Comment: Note: Your files may have the lowercase extension *.pdf instead of *.PDF, this is the sam format, so the only chnage is you write .pdf instead of .PDF

Comment: Note2: If you're comparing with Hash'es, then you're probably facing a problem with the metadata. You have to remove it first.

Comment: Note3: The given methods will also work on macOS and Linux with minimal modification

Comment: even,
getting this error.                                                                                                           please send me sample code for convert from pdf to text.      here my task is i have 2 pdf documents, in this there are some uniq ids. Now I am compere these files with missing ids by using powershell script?

Comment: pdftk : The term 'pdftk' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling 
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:2 char:1
+ pdftk [output file].tmp background [C:\demo2\koti\Powershell\task.pdf ...
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pdftk:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: @NaPeruKoTi It looks like PDFTK isn't installed/is installed in an improper directory. While installing, you have to install pdftk.exe into a folder that is in your PATH. I'm not sure which folders are in PATH on Windows or how you add folders to the PATH, you have to search for this yourself.

Comment: A basic example to convert PDF to text is given in my answer, but basically, after installing Xpdf command line tools, you have to run the command `pdftotext [pdf file name].pdf` (without the square brackets) and xpdf will create a file [pdf file name].txt