# Comparing 2 pdf files with imagemagick and pdftk to produce an output file with Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Tags: compare, imagemagick, pdftk

I am trying to compare 2 pdf files in Linux, using `imagemagick` and `pdftk` to produce an output file showing the difference as red pixels.

I have looked at: [PDF compare on linux command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469157/pdf-compare-on-linux-command-line) and [How to compare 2 PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67444492/how-to-compare-2-pdf-files)

I installed `imagemagick` and `pdftk`, to use with the `compare` command:

```
compare -verbose -debug coder $PDF_1 $PDF_2 -compose src $OUT_FILE.tmp
pdftk $OUT_FILE.tmp background $PDF_1 output $OUT_FILE
```

On attempting the compare command:

```
compare -verbose -debug coder SQK_2012_4th_Ed.pdf Subquantum_kinetics__6th_edition_4c.pdf -compose src SQK_output.tmp pdftk SQK_output.tmp background SQK_2012_4th_Ed.pdf output SQK_output
```

I get output:

```
compare-im6.q16: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PDF' @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/413.
compare-im6.q16: unable to open image `SQK_output.tmp': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2874.
compare-im6.q16: unable to open image `SQK_output.tmp': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2874.
compare-im6.q16: no decode delegate for this image format `TMP' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/572.
compare-im6.q16: unable to open image `pdftk': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2874.
compare-im6.q16: unable to open image `pdftk': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2874.
compare-im6.q16: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/572.
compare-im6.q16: unable to open image `SQK_output.tmp': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2874.
compare-im6.q16: unable to open image `SQK_output.tmp': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2874.
compare-im6.q16: no decode delegate for this image format `TMP' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/572.
compare-im6.q16: unable to open image `background': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2874.
compare-im6.q16: unable to open image `background': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2874.
compare-im6.q16: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/572.
compare-im6.q16: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PDF' @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/413.
compare-im6.q16: unable to open image `output': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2874.
compare-im6.q16: unable to open image `output': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2874.
compare-im6.q16: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/572.
```

Can someone prompt me in the right direction to solve this?